# What is $E(W_s|W_t)$ , $0<s<t$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation

Any thoughts on what is $  X_{s,t} = E(Ws|Wt)$  when $0<s<t $.

i.e conditional expectation of a Brownian motion $W_s$ given its future state $W_t$.

E.g.

Expectation ( is =2 zero ? )

Variance ( for which $s$ does it reach its max in $[0,t]$)

Analytical formula (  $X_{s,t} = a W_s + b W_t$ ? Brownian Bridge ?)

Comment: Hi Zugulu, you probably stand a much better chance of getting some help with this if you explain in detail what the $W_s$ and $X_{s,t}$ are.

Comment: I thought it was obvious from the tags. I will put more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: About $W_s|W_t$ and $\mathbb{E}\left(W_s|W_t\right)$**

Thanks to OP's clarification, the question is concerning about $W_s|W_t$, a Brownian bridge. Here are the respective updates.

Still make use of these two facts:

- $W_s-\left(s/t\right)W_t$ is a sum of two independent normal random variables with zero means, i.e.,
  $$
  W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t=\left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)W_s-\frac{s}{t}\left(W_t-W_s\right),
  $$
  for which it is also a normal random variable with a zero mean, and
- $W_s-\left(s/t\right)W_t$ and $W_t$ are independent normal random variables with zero means, with their independence able to be checked via their zero correlation coefficient.

Thus we may write in the form of
$$
W_s|W_t=\left(W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t\right)\bigg|W_t+\frac{s}{t}W_t|W_t=\left(W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t\right)+\frac{s}{t}W_t|W_t,
$$
where $W_s-\left(s/t\right)W_t$ in the last equation shall be understood as a random variable independent from $W_t$, even if $W_t$ appears as part of its component.

With this in mind, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(W_s|W_t\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{s}{t}W_t|W_t\right)=\frac{s}{t}W_t.
$$

Likewise,
\begin{align}
\text{Var}\left(W_s|W_t\right)&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(W_s-\mathbb{E}\left(W_s|W_t\right)\right)^2|W_t\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left[\left(W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t\right)^2\bigg|W_t\right]\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t\right)^2.
\end{align}
Recall the first fact in above that
$$
W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t=\left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)W_s-\frac{s}{t}\left(W_t-W_s\right)
$$
is a sum of two independent normal random variables. Hence
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t\right)^2=\left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)^2s+\left(\frac{s}{t}\right)^2\left(t-s\right)=\frac{s}{t}\left(t-s\right).
$$

---

**Original Post: Mistaken $W_s|W_t$ (a conditioned process) as $W_s/W_t$ (a ratio)**

It could be hopeless to evaluate any moment of $W_s/W_t$, because it is not defined for [Cauchy distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution).

In fact, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard normal random variables, then $X/Y$ follows a standard Cauchy distribution. For the non-standard-normal cases, you may refer to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Gaussian_ratio_distribution) for more details.

Now get back to the Brownian motion case. As per $0<s<t$, we have

- $W_s-\left(s/t\right)W_t$ is a sum of two independent normal random variables with zero means, i.e.,
  $$
  W_s-\frac{s}{t}W_t=\left(1-\frac{s}{t}\right)W_s-\frac{s}{t}\left(W_t-W_s\right),
  $$
  for which it is also a normal random variable with a zero mean, and
- $W_s-\left(s/t\right)W_t$ and $W_t$ are independent normal random variables with zero means, with their independence able to be checked via their zero correlation coefficient.

Therefore,
$$
\frac{W_s}{W_t}=\frac{W_s-\left(s/t\right)W_t}{W_t}+\frac{s}{t},
$$
as a shift of the ratio of two independent normal random variables with zero means, follows a Cauchy distribution.

Comment: Thanks. But this is conditional expectation and NOT a ratio.

Comment: @Zugulu: I see. Thank you for this clarification. I am updating my post. Yet conventionally, a conditional expectation is always written as $\mathbb{E}\left(W_s|W_t\right)$ instead of a slash.

Comment: ok will update "/" to "|"

Comment: @Zugulu: Awesome :-)

Comment: @Zugulu: Conditional expectation and variance updated. Generally, a Brownian bridge does not have an easy expression. You may refer to [this reference](http://disi.unal.edu.co/~gjhernandezp/mathcomm/slides/bm.pdf), especially sections 4 and 6 therein, for more information.

Comment: @Zugulu: You are welcome. Sure. You may regard it as an empirical discovery. Generally, we "hate" $W_s|W_t$ because we would have no idea about it. We hope to construct a variable independent from $W_t$, so that the conditioning could drop. An intuition would be to consider the form $W_s+\alpha W_t$. Our hope is to make $W_s+\alpha W_t$ independent from $W_t$, or equivalently, $\text{Cov}\left(W_s+\alpha W_t,W_t\right)=0$. This implies that $\alpha=-s/t$.